# Attempting to copy an active sheet and open a new sheet but with only specific cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add to my script to copy only certain cells from a template I have set up.  Currently I have a menu item that creates a "copy" of the template sheet, but it is currently copying everything.  I am also no pro at this and have only been trying to figure out this coding system for a couple of days.  Any help would be wonderful.  Below is the script I currently have.

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Copy Template", functionName: "newSheet"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("New Sheet", menu);
}

function newSheet() {
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[0];
  var sheetName = formatDate()+' '+user;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 1, {template: templateSheet});
}

function formatDate() {
  var month, day, d = new Date();
  month = ('0'+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  day = ('0'+d.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return d.getFullYear()+'-'+month+'-'+day;
}

function onEdit() {
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[0];
  var ss, date;
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  date = new Date();
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('j2').setValue(date).setNumberFormat('H:mm');
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('i2').setValue(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probally use range:

```
function newSheet() {
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[0];
  var sheetName = formatDate()+' '+user;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var getRange =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName([TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME]).getRange('YOUR RANGE Ex A1:A10').getValues();
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```

And after use again get the range where you want them and use SetValues(getRange)

Comment: I have attempted to set a range for the certain cells that are needed to copy but with the script making a completely new document there is no destination source as the sheet is not created until after the user selects the menu item.  Unless I am missing something about setting ranges and moving them to a different sheet.